# Using booleans in ng-if from res.render (AngularJS, Express)

Tags: angularjs, express

Fairly inexperienced with web development, any help/suggestions/corrections would be appreciated.

I'm trying to have a webpage that has different features if someone is an admin or not. I'm using passport for the admin log in and authentication. I want to pass a boolean, say isAdmin, like so:

res.render('thisPage', { isAdmin: (req.isAuthenticated)});

Then access this in the html file

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var isAdmin = "{{ isAdmin }}";
</script>

<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-if="isAdmin">
    <app-info></app-info>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="app/MainController.js"></script>

<!-- Directives -->
<script src="app/directives/directive.js"></script>
```

This is just for testing currently- but even when I verify that isAdmin is true (server side), this nothing shows up at this url when I run the server on localhost. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: are you using handlebars or jade to render your templates in express?

Comment: just using html as my engine- is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is ng-show/ng-hide, not ng-if

```
<div ng-show="isAdmin">...</div> // Show if isAdmin is true
<div ng-hide="!isAdmin">...</div> // Hide if the user is NOT admin
```

Comment: So I added an ng-show block, one for each isAdmin and !isAdmin. Still if I make sure that req.isAuthenticated = true, the isAdmin div won't show. Is there an error in the way I try to access isAdmin in my html file?

Comment: You will need to show us your controller and how 'isAdmin' is being set.  If isAdmin is being set as a String, for example,  'true' and 'false' are both boolean TRUE.  You need to make sure that isAdmin is truly being set as a boolean value.